# How to find noncommutative product of two expression

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I have the following function 
$$
B(n)=x \alpha ^n-y \alpha ^n q^n
 + \epsilon  \left(x \alpha ^{n+1}-y \alpha ^{n+1} q^{n+1}\right). $$
Here, I want to find the product $B(n)^2$ or $B(n)*B(n+1)$ where the variables $x$ and $y$ are non-commutative i.e. $xy\neq yx$. Is there any way to achieve this in Mathematica ?

For example, when I try to find the product in Mathematica, I find that

$$
B(n)^2 = -2 x y \epsilon ^2 \alpha ^{2 n+2} q^{n+1}-2 x y \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+1} q^{n+1}+y^2 \epsilon ^2 \alpha ^{2 n+2} q^{2 n+2}+2 y^2 \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+1} q^{2 n+1}+y^2 \alpha ^{2 n} q^{2 n}-2 x y \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+1} q^n-2 x y \alpha ^{2 n} q^n+x^2 \epsilon ^2 \alpha ^{2 n+2}+2 x^2 \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+1}+x^2 \alpha ^{2 n}
$$
and 
$$
B(n)*B(n+1) = -x y \epsilon ^2 \alpha ^{2 n+3} q^{n+1}-x y \epsilon ^2 \alpha ^{2 n+3} q^{n+2}-2 x y \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+2} q^{n+1}-x y \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+2} q^{n+2}-x y \alpha ^{2 n+1} q^{n+1}+y^2 \epsilon ^2 \alpha ^{2 n+3} q^{2 n+3}+2 y^2 \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+2} q^{2 n+2}+y^2 \alpha ^{2 n+1} q^{2 n+1}-x y \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+2} q^n-x y \alpha ^{2 n+1} q^n+x^2 \epsilon ^2 \alpha ^{2 n+3}+2 x^2 \epsilon  \alpha ^{2 n+2}+x^2 \alpha ^{2 n+1}.
$$
But it must be that $xy \neq yx$.

Comment: There is a question similar to my topic that is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320735/how-to-define-some-variables-as-non-commutative-in-maxima. I want to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: Have you seen [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html)?

Comment: @CATrevillian;

Yes I saw it but I couldn't use for my case. If is it possible, could you please explain how to apply NonCommutativeMultiply to my function $B(n)$?

Comment: Shouldn’t it just be `B[n]**B[n+1]`?

Answer (score 3):

In the light of Mathematica's [NonCommutativeMultiply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html), I have solved the problem as follows:

```
B[n_] := (a ** x + b ** y) + (b ** x + a ** y ** q^n);

ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
 Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &]

ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___]] := 
 Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]

ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a]

B[n]**B[n + 1] // ExpandNCM // ExpandAll

= a ** x ** a ** x + a ** x ** b ** x + a ** x ** b ** y + 
  b ** x ** a ** x + b ** x ** b ** x + b ** x ** b ** y + 
  b ** y ** a ** x + b ** y ** b ** x + b ** y ** b ** y + 
  a ** x ** a ** y ** q^(1 + n) + a ** y ** q^n ** a ** x + 
  a ** y ** q^n ** b ** x + a ** y ** q^n ** b ** y + 
  b ** x ** a ** y ** q^(1 + n) + b ** y ** a ** y ** q^(1 + n) + 
  a ** y ** q^n ** a ** y ** q^(1 + n)
```

The only problem is that you must simplify some expressions with manually.

Thank you @CATrevillian.

Comment: Nice job! I was gonna try to comment on a cool extension wherein you could use `TagSet` or the-like to define the behavior of `Power` in the case of this type of `NonCommutativeMultiply`, but alas, I couldn't make the extension function properly. This is awesome! Great work here, drxy.

Comment: Dear @CATrevillian;

I have seen before  NonCommutativeMultiply. But my inspiration came from after reading your post. So thank you very much.

Comment: your constructs are quite advanced, for me at least, so I thank you for this in return! If I might ask for clarification, can you explain the pieces of your code, how they work/your choices in how you formatted them?

Comment: @CATrevillian; I have edited the answer. For the sake of simplicity, I define different $B(n)$ but I think that this code is more clear than previous one.